# How to repaint all JPanels upon resizing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I currently have 2 JPanels being added to a JFrame. Upon resizing the window, only the most recently added JPanel gets resized. How can I ensure that all JPanels resize? In my program, I launch a firework and have gridlines. I want each to hug the bottom of the screen.

With this code, the launched firework resizes to hug, but the grid lines dont:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(950,800);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

GuiTest test = new GuiTest();
frame.add(test, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
frame.setVisible(true);

Grid grid = new Grid();
frame.add(grid);
frame.setVisible(true);

FireworkP canvas = new FireworkP(150, 45, 7, 2);
frame.add(canvas);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

With this code, the opposite occurs:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(950,800);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

GuiTest test = new GuiTest();
frame.add(test, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
frame.setVisible(true);

FireworkP canvas = new FireworkP(150, 45, 7, 2);
frame.add(canvas);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
frame.setVisible(true);

Grid grid = new Grid();
frame.add(grid);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Default state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gCpV.png

Code 1 resized: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4gf5.png

Code 2 resized: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR8Kd.png

Comment: All Swing components should repaint themselves if resized.  You should probably assume that one JPanel wasn't resized or was for some other reason not updated.  Are you using any custom (not Swing, but your own work) components?

Comment: You call `frame.add(canvas);` twice with different parameters.  Only the last one will be active.  You can only have one main content at a time.

Comment: So is there any way to have a separate grid line class or should I just combine them? I dont understand why they arent both active.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> So is there any way to have a separate grid line class or should I just combine them?

You build a parent / child relationship.

So you logic would be something like:

```
FireworkP foreground = new FireworkP(150, 45, 7, 2);
foreground.setOpaque( false );

Grid background = new Grid();
background.add(foreground);

frame.add(background);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The above assumes:

1. your FireworkP and Grid classes are JPanels where you do custom painting.
2. your classes use an appropriate layout manager

So now you GUI has a structure like:

```
- frame
    - background
        - foreground
```

So you have components that can paint themselves on top of one another on the Z axis.

If you add more than one component to the same panel then the components are painted on the X/Y axis

Comment: @mander39 Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). I would guess your fireworks have a preferred size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of your panel so the layout manager can do its job.

Comment: Alright, using the tutorial everything shows up, but its still onjly updating the position of 1/2 panels. I think its just time to scrap the code, having 2 panels just does not work. Ill put the gird in the firework paintComponent somehow.

Comment: Took 5 mins to just combine them, anyone reading this for help just combine your paintComponents and add gui elements that alter and repaint the graphics accordingly